# How to Set format for Text in stimulsoft

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

I use this code for pass a Number to stimulsoft report:

```
 stiReport1.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\MyReport.mrt");
 (stiReport1.GetComponentByName("Text35") as StiText).Text = Mynumber.ToString();
 stiReport1.RegData(databaseDataSet.Mytable);
 stiReport1.Show();
```

I set Text35 Format in MyReport same this pic:
https://i.imgsafe.org/0a7bb2d.png

But it dosen't Work and For example Show 12000 instead 12,000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it in c# and pass a formatted string to report:

```
Mynumber.ToString("##,###")
```

Answer (score 2):

The Text Format have no matter. The number is converted to string in your code here :

```
= Mynumber.ToString();
```

If you need to change the format you should do it in ToString() method.

The other way is to use a numeric report variable, use it in the Text35 text component and set its value with next code:

```
report.Dictionary.Variables["Variable1"].Value = yourNumber;
```